# How do I generate and download a PDF from the following data?

Tags: reactjs, puppeteer, pdf-generation

I am getting the following response from backend where the pdf is generated using `puppeteer`  this is the kind of data that I get:

> %PDF-1.4
>
> %����
>
> 1 0 obj
>
> <</Creator (Chromium)
>
> /Producer (Skia/PDF m117)
>
> /CreationDate (D:20231030121554+00'00')
>
> /ModDate (D:20231030121554+00'00')>>
>
> endobj
>
> 3 0 obj
>
> <</ca 1
>
> /BM /Normal>>
>
> endobj
>
> 4 0 obj
>
> <</ca .0314/Filter /FlateDecode
>
> /Length 4339>> stream
>
> x��[�۸��g<�O�@�/�}���@Q�(�`�)Y3{�bg�t������l�-��
>
> t3W��)���(�J���%��@G@��Ն�.a�p��i�/

I did the following but it didn't help:

```
     const arr = new Uint8Array(response?.data);
        const blob = new Blob([arr], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        // const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });

        // Create a URL for the Blob
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Create a download link
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'example.pdf'; // Specify the filename for the download
        a.style.display = 'none';

        // Add the link to the DOM and trigger a click event
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();

        // Clean up by removing the link and revoking the URL
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

and this :

```
 const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
```

But I just get an empty pdf, I can on the backend that the PDF is generated and is fine but I can't seem to download it on the front-end ( React ).

Comment: Can you update the question with your fetch request

Comment: We'll need a complete, runnable [mcve] to help here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the response, the issue was when I was fetching the response I didn't to pass `responseType: Arraybuffer.` in the request get request.